# Horizontal alignement of two tikzcd

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tikz-cd

How can I put two copies of this tikzcd on the same line?

```
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=2.5em]
& \text{A} \arrow[dash]{dr}{1} \\
\text{B} \arrow[dash]{ur}{2} \arrow[dash]{rr}{3} && \text{C}
\end{tikzcd}
\]
```

Comment: If you want upright letters, you should use `\mathrm{A}`, rather than `\text{A}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=2.5em]
& \text{A} \arrow[dash]{dr}{1} \\
\text{B} \arrow[dash]{ur}{2} \arrow[dash]{rr}{3} && \text{C}
\end{tikzcd}
\quad
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=2.5em]
& \text{A} \arrow[dash]{dr}{1} \\
\text{B} \arrow[dash]{ur}{2} \arrow[dash]{rr}{3} && \text{C}
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you have different diagrams, you may want to make use of the `baseline` option,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=2.5em,baseline=(B.base)]
& \text{A} \arrow[dash]{dr}{1} & \\
|[alias=B]|\text{B} \arrow[dash]{ur}{2} \arrow[dash]{rr}{3} && \text{C}
\end{tikzcd}
\quad
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=2.5em,baseline=(B.base)]
& \text{A} \arrow[dash]{dr}{1} &\\
|[alias=B]|\text{B} \arrow[dash]{ur}{2}
\arrow[dash]{dr}{4} \arrow[dash]{rr}{3} && \text{C} \\
& \text{D} &
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

or put the diagrams in `\vcenter{\hbox{...}}` to vertically center them.

Comment: Sure! That's done.